# Groovy: How to check if a list contains items from another list that includes regex format

Tags: regex, list, groovy

I have been given two lists and I need to check whether any items in the sites list are in the ignoredSites. When I run the code below it only prints out google.co.uk however, should it not also print out amazon.co.uk and the groovy-lang.org?

Could someone explain why it doesn't

```
def ignoredSites = ["www.amazon.com", /amazon.co.*/, /www.scala-lang.org/,/google.co.uk/, ~/htt(p|ps):\/\/www\.amazon\.co.*/, "groovy-lang.org"]
def sites = ["amazon.co.uk", ~/groo{2}vy-lang\.org/, "google.co.uk", "amazon.com", ~/scala.*/]


sites.each { site ->
    ignoredSites.contains(site) ? println("Ignored: ${site}") : ""
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are mixing regex and strings in arrays. I suggest you to have them in separate lists.
Second of all be aware of groovy slashy strings.

I modified your code in order for you to see [slashy strings](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_slashy_string) (amazon.co.*, www.scala-lang.org, google.co.uk) are actually interpreted as strings and not as regex as expected.

And in your case since you are mixing regex and strings in arrays, check have to be done differently:

```
def ignoredSites = ["www.amazon.com", /amazon.co.*/, /www.scala-lang.org/,/google.co.uk/, ~/htt(p|ps):\/\/www\.amazon\.co.*/, "groovy-lang.org"]
def sites = ["amazon.co.uk", ~/groo{2}vy-lang\.org/, "google.co.uk", "amazon.com", ~/scala.*/]


println '==========sites============'
sites.each { site ->
  println site.toString() + " == "+ site.class
}
println '==========ignoredSites============'
ignoredSites.each { site ->
  println site.toString() + " == "+ site.class
}
println '======================'

sites.each { site ->
     if(site.class.equals(java.util.regex.Pattern)){
       ignoredSites.each{ is ->
         if(is.class.equals(java.lang.String)){
           if(is.matches(site)) println("Ignored: ${site}") //string = regex
         } else {
           //can't match 2 regex
         }
       }
     } else {
       ignoredSites.each{ is ->
         if(is.class.equals(java.lang.String)){
           if(is.equals(site)) println("Ignored: ${site}") //string = regex
         } else {
           if(site.matches(is)) println("Ignored3: ${site}") //string = regex
         }
       }
     }
}
```

**Edited**

If you run the code, with printing element types, you will notice following thing:

```
==========sites============
amazon.co.uk == class java.lang.String
groo{2}vy-lang\.org == class java.util.regex.Pattern
google.co.uk == class java.lang.String
amazon.com == class java.lang.String
scala.* == class java.util.regex.Pattern
==========ignoredSites============
www.amazon.com == class java.lang.String
amazon.co.* == class java.lang.String
www.scala-lang.org == class java.lang.String
google.co.uk == class java.lang.String
htt(p|ps)://www\.amazon\.co.* == class java.util.regex.Pattern
groovy-lang.org == class java.lang.String
======================
```

So,  amazon.co.uk is not matched, because regular expression that should match it:

```
amazon.co.* == class java.lang.String
```

is interpreted as a String by the groovy, because of slashy strings.
On the other hand

```
groo{2}vy-lang\.org == class java.util.regex.Pattern
```

is a regex, but `{2}` in it, means that o appears exactly 2 times.
In short, `groo{2}vy-lang\.org` will match `grooovy-lang.org` (note three o in there).

Comment: thank you for your feedback, but, I'm not changing the code as it is part of a technical test for a job interview. The question that they asked is to explain why each element in sites would/would not appear in ignoredSites. I'm trying to understand why the  amazon.co.uk and the groovy-lang.org don't show when I execute the code.

Answer (score 2):

It would be rather unusual to have a site being a pattern but assuming that is what you meant:

```
def ignoredSites = ["www.amazon.com", /amazon.co.*/, /www.scala-lang.org/,/google.co.uk/, ~/htt(p|ps):\/\/www\.amazon\.co.*/, "groovy-lang.org"]
def sites = ["amazon.co.uk", ~/gro{2}vy-lang\.org/, "google.co.uk", "amazon.com", ~/scala.*/]

sites.findAll { site ->
    ignoredSites.find{ it == site || (site in String && site.matches(it) || (it in String && it.matches(site))) }
}.each{ println "Ignored: $it" }
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I disagree with the accepted answer and it looks like the trap the interviewer wants you to fall into.

To check this, you can simply change `~/groo{2}vy-lang\.org/` to `~/gro{2}vy-lang\.org/` and see for yourself that `"groovy-lang.org"` still won't be ignored.

This is because `java.util.Collection.contains()` isn't trying to be clever (probably because it isn't overwritten by Groovy) and simply checks, in this particular case, for equality (as defined [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object))).

So `"groovy-lang.org" ==~ /gro{2}vy-lang.org/` (the pattern matches) but `"groovy-lang.org" != ~/gro{2}vy-lang.org/` (they're not equal objects and [groovy truth](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#Groovy-Truth) doesn't abstract that particular case).

The "ignore" test is based on object equality, not on pattern matching as the interviewer probably voluntarily misleads you to believe.

Hope this helps, and I'm not mistaken.